# Counting most common value in Arbitrary number of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have hundreds of dictionaries that look like this. They all have the same keys (New York, Chicago etc..) but have different values. There are no missing values.

```
[{'New York': 'cloudy', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'},
 {'New York': 'cloudy', 'Chicago': 'hailing', 'Seattle': 'sunny'},
 {'New York': 'sunny', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'}, 
 {'New York': 'hailing', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle':'snowy'}]
```

I want to count the most common "weather" value for each key. And then combine them all into one final list that just outputs each city with the most common key value it has.

```
{'New York': 'cloudy', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your list of dictionaries into a pandas DataFrame, count values for each city, find the index of the maximal value:

```
import pandas as pd
typical = pd.DataFrame(your_list_of_dicts).apply(pd.value_counts).idxmax()
#Chicago      snowy
#New York    cloudy
#Seattle      rainy
```

Make it a dictionary if needed:

```
typical.to_dict()
#{'Chicago': 'snowy', 'New York': 'cloudy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can iterate over the list to group each city with all its related weather values and then use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
d = [{'New York': 'cloudy', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'}, {'New York': 'cloudy', 'Chicago': 'hailing', 'Seattle': 'sunny'}, {'New York': 'sunny', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'}, {'New York': 'hailing', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'snowy'}]
weather = {i:Counter([c[i] for c in d]).most_common(1)[0][0] for b in d for i in b}
```

Output:

```
{'New York': 'cloudy', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'}
```

Edit: assuming all dictionaries in `d` contain the same keys, only the latter attributes need to be iterated over from the very first dictionary in the list:

```
weather = {i:Counter([c[i] for c in d]).most_common(1)[0][0] for i in d[0]}
```

Comment: If the keys are the same for all dictionaries, do you really need `for b in d for i in b` every time? Can't you just have `for i in d[0]`? That will make it much faster

Comment: @slider Very good point. I originally used `for b in d for i in b` to be as robust as possible, however, I also added your suggestion as a edit. The latter is certainly much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a one-liner `dictionary comprehension` then?, like:

```
print({k:max([i[k] for i in weather],key=[i[k] for i in weather].count) for k in list(weather[0].keys())})
```

Now you get the desired output as:

```
{'New York': 'cloudy', 'Chicago': 'snowy', 'Seattle': 'rainy'}
```